# Xamarin.Forms ListView with different controls per row?

Tags: c#, listview, xamarin.forms

With iOS and Android, I can create scrollable listviews, bound to a list where each row can have different controls.  How do I do this with Xamarin.Forms?  From what I can tell, the ListView control only takes a single templete and there is no overload or callback when each row is created where I can change the controls (which is what I can do with iOS and Android).

Comment: If Xamarin.Forms is consistent with other XAML-based Frameworks (such as WPF), it should have the concept of ["implicit DataTemplates"](http://10rem.net/blog/2011/04/13/silverlight-5-working-with-implicit-templates)

Comment: @HighCore except it's not. It's based on XAML but that's about where it ends - no styles, no templates

Answer (score 2):

You can use TableView. In TableView you specify each Custom ViewCell per Row, but you lost the Item Selection Handler of the ListView. For example:

```
        var table = new TableView {
            Intent = TableIntent.Settings,
            Root = new TableRoot("Table Name"),
            HasUnevenRows = true,
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
            BackgroundColor = Color.Transparent
        };

        var section = new TableSection ();

        //dataList in my case is the list of elements that populate each row
        dataList.ForEach (e => {
            //Add custom Cells to the TableSection
            section.Add(new ContactCardCell{BindingContext = e});
        });

        table.Root.Add (section);
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple way is to use a converter and show/hide the content you  want for each cell.

You can bind a item to the visibility of a grid, in the middle you use a converter to check if  you want to show or hide the grid depending on the item.

this is the possible workaround.

I hope the Xamarin Forms teams adds a ContentView that could have it's view binded to in the future or offer a CellTemplateSelector in the cells.

Comment: I don't think a converter is the best solution.  What I really want is to be able to specify a template per row, rather than a template for the entire list.  Is there a way to do that?

Comment: You are right is not the best but no there's no way to do that right now.

Answer (score 0):

How different are your rows?

If they are very different you'd need to make a custom cell renderer and possibly a custom listview and renderer for it.

If the rows aren't that different you may want to try using a superset of the controls and hide the ones you don't need based on item bindings - this would likely require you to add extra fields in your cell's viewmodel

You may also want to try a Scrollview with a StackLayout inside - definitely not the native l&f so depending on what is your goal this may not apply.